# How to line elements side by side, regardless of container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a container with some `divs` in it. I want to line up the `divs` side by side. If they don't fit into the container, still place them next to each other, but outside of the container. I tried using `white-space: nowrap`. This breaks them out of the grandfather container but also the parent container. Here is an example of the problem with `nowrap`.

```css
.container{
  border: dashed;
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
.row {
  border: dotted red;
}
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  border: dotted green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class='row'>
       <div class="block">
         <p>
         Stuff
         </p>
       </div>
       <div class="block">
         <p>
         Stuff
         </p>
       </div>
       <div class="block">
         <p>
         Stuff
         </p>
       </div>
       <div class="block">
         <p>
         Stuff
         </p>
       </div> 
       <div class="block">
         <p>
         Stuff
         </p>
       </div>
   
   <div class="block">
     <p>
     Stuff
     </p>
   </div>
   <div class="block">
     <p>
     Stuff
     </p>
   </div>
   <div class="block">
     <p>
     Stuff
     </p>
   </div>
   <div class="block">
     <p>
     Stuff
     </p>
   </div>
   <div class="block">
     <p>
     Stuff
     </p>
   </div>
   <div class="block">
     <p>
     Stuff
     </p>
   </div>
   <div class="block">
     <p>
     Stuff
     </p>
   </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The black border is the window, the red border is the parent div, and the green border represents blocks of data.

I need to just escape the grandparent div, while the parent div will still wrap around the content, even if it escapes the grandparent div.

Any advise?

EDIT: None of the answers worked for me. I'm still not able to surround the children in my example.

Comment: Your code snippet appears to work as you wish

Comment: I want the parent `div` to retain its content. The red border should wrap around all the `stuff` in green.

Answer (score 1):

Give `display: table` or `display: inline-block` to `.row`:

```
.container{
    border: dashed;
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.row {
    display: table; // inline-block
    border: dotted red;
}
.block {
    display: inline-block;
    border: dotted green;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

CodePen: http://codepen.io/theblindprophet/pen/rLJzqG

Answer (score 0):

A sort of hack-y solution, use `outline` instead of `border`, and slap padding on the window (or block margin collapse (actual window will block it) and use `margin` on the "parent `div`"). Not as flexible as `border`, but exhibits the behavior you desire.

```css
.container{
  border: dashed;
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space:nowrap;
  padding:3px;
}
.row {
  outline:3px dotted red;
}
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  border: dotted green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class='row'>
       <div class="block">
         <p>
         Stuff
         </p>
       </div>
       <div class="block">
         <p>
         Stuff
         </p>
       </div>
       <div class="block">
         <p>
         Stuff
         </p>
       </div>
       <div class="block">
         <p>
         Stuff
         </p>
       </div> 
       <div class="block">
         <p>
         Stuff
         </p>
       </div>
   
   <div class="block">
     <p>
     Stuff
     </p>
   </div>
   <div class="block">
     <p>
     Stuff
     </p>
   </div>
   <div class="block">
     <p>
     Stuff
     </p>
   </div>
   <div class="block">
     <p>
     Stuff
     </p>
   </div>
   <div class="block">
     <p>
     Stuff
     </p>
   </div>
   <div class="block">
     <p>
     Stuff
     </p>
   </div>
   <div class="block">
     <p>
     Stuff
     </p>
   </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add `display: inline-block;` to `.row` it works as I understand you want it to.

https://jsfiddle.net/2caxuhu6/

Answer (score 0):

This was easy

```css
.container{
  border: dashed;
  width: 25%;

  white-space:nowrap;
}
.row {
  border: dotted red;
    display: inline-block;
}
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  border: dotted green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class='row'>
       <div class="block">
         <p>
         Stuff
         </p>
       </div>
       <div class="block">
         <p>
         Stuff
         </p>
       </div>
       <div class="block">
         <p>
         Stuff
         </p>
       </div>
       <div class="block">
         <p>
         Stuff
         </p>
       </div> 
       <div class="block">
         <p>
         Stuff
         </p>
       </div>
   
   <div class="block">
     <p>
     Stuff
     </p>
   </div>
   <div class="block">
     <p>
     Stuff
     </p>
   </div>
   <div class="block">
     <p>
     Stuff
     </p>
   </div>
   <div class="block">
     <p>
     Stuff
     </p>
   </div>
   <div class="block">
     <p>
     Stuff
     </p>
   </div>
   <div class="block">
     <p>
     Stuff
     </p>
   </div>
   <div class="block">
     <p>
     Stuff
     </p>
   </div>
   </div>
</div>
```